# How to use the getLogo function of the Spil API

Tags: javascript, html

How would I use the getLogo function to display the Spil Logo on inside my HTML5 game?

Here's the link to their docs

http://developers.spilgames.com/wiki/Developer_Platform_-_Learning_center_-_HTML5_API_getLogo

I don't understand if it's meant to display their logo automatically, or if I'm meant to do something with the object data it returns, and if so how would use it?

Comment: The docs say `Use this method to retrieve an object containing the logo configuration data.` so you have to do something with the object.

Answer (score 0):

We provide basically only two properties: a URL to the image and a function. What you need to do within your game is attach the Javascript link to the image.

A typical logo implementation looks like this for a DOM implementation. But of course this depends on the nature of your game and if you're using a framework:

```
GameAPI.loadAPI(function (apiInstance) {

    // getLogo example
    var logoData = apiInstance.Branding.getLogo();

    // Create a DOM element and use the values returned by the call
    var logo = document.createElement('img');

    logo.src = logoData.image;
    logo.addEventListener('click', logoData.action);

    document.body.appendChild(logo);
});
```

You can find a tutorial complete with jsFiddle example here: http://developers.spilgames.com/wiki/Developer_Platform_-_Learning_center_-_HTML5_API_-_(Tutorial)_Get_logo

If you run into technical issues, you can always get in touch with the Tech Support team using the "Support" tab on this page: http://developers.spilgames.com/contact

Hopefully this answers your question!